# How did movie makers make "Odie" act with an animated Character in Garfield?

Tags: animation, garfield

As per Wikipedia

> "Garfield: The Movie is a 2004 American family comedy film directed by Peter Hewitt inspired by Jim Davis' comic strip of the same name.
>   It stars Breckin Meyer as Jon Arbuckle, Jennifer Love Hewitt as Dr.
>   Liz Wilson, and features Bill Murray as the voice of Garfield.
>   Garfield was created with computer animation, though all other animals
>   were real."

Garfield is a animated Character in the movie. Garfield's friend in the movie is "Odie" a real dog.

How did the movie makers make "Odie" act with an animated character?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How did the movie makers make "Odie" act with an animated character.

## By using a couple of **very** well trained dogs...

> The part of Odie was played by two Dachshund mixes named "Tyler" and "Chloe"

The dance-off in particular was a combination of blue-screen, the dog reacting to trainer commands and many, many takes.

> Garfield shoves Odie off the chair various times, and they engage in a dance-off competition that features Odie hopping around on his back legs. Though they're having fun together, Garfield propels Odie across the porch when his other cat friends show up.
>
> For this sequence, trainers first positioned "Tyler" in a stay position on a blue screen floor. As "Tyler" hopped on his back legs, a second trainer called the dog to come in the opposite direction and cued him to spin in circles in one spot.
>
> This same action was repeated for various takes from different angles, and "Tyler" was conditioned and prepped for this scene for three weeks before actual filming began.

For this and many other details on the various sequences see [**Humane Hollywood**](http://humanehollywood.org/index.php/movie-archive/item/garfield-the-movie)

Comment: That's kinda cruel on the animal though

Comment: Not really...stunt dogs are highly trained and **very** well cared for while on set AND there are strict rules about treatment of animals in movies.  Of course, some people object to the use of *any* animals but that's a subjective issue.